# javascript dynamic prototype

Tags: javascript

I want extend a new JS object while creation with other object passing a parameter.
This code does not work, because I only can extend object without dynamic parameter.

```
otherObject = function(id1){
    this.id = id1;
};

otherObject.prototype.test =function(){
    alert(this.id);
};

testObject = function(id2) {
    this.id=id2;
};

testObject.prototype = new otherObject("id2");/* id2 should be testObject this.id */


var a = new testObject("variable");
a.test();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use your debugger and find the syntax error

Comment: Read this: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: Simply fixing the syntax and reference errors made it alert `"variable"`. Not very exciting

Comment: otherObject should extend testObject

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the obvious syntax error, the correct JavaScript way of inheritance is this:

```
// constructors are named uppercase by convention
function OtherObject(id1) {
    this.id = id1;
};
OtherObject.prototype.test = function() {
    alert(this.id);
};

function TestObject(id2) {
    // call "super" constructor on this object:
    OtherObject.call(this, id2);
};
// create a prototype object inheriting from the other one
TestObject.prototype = Object.create(OtherObject.prototype);
// if you want them to be equal (share all methods), you can simply use
TestObject.prototype = OtherObject.prototype;


var a = new TestObject("variable");
a.test(); // alerts "variable"
```

You will find lots of tutorials about this on the web.

Comment: line 19: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: Cannot find function test in object [object Object]

Comment: Works, but Eclipse JS can not see inheritance like object.protoype = new ();

Comment: @Imp: No, of course not. If you want to support them, there are [simple polyfills](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create/#Polyfill) to import...

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly what you desire, but

```
otherObject.prototype.test = function () { 
    alert(this.id); 
};
```

would be correct.

And this

testObject.prototype = new otherObject(id2);

will not work unless id2 is set before.

Try the following

```
   var OtherObject = function () {
   }
   OtherObject.prototype.test = function () {
       alert (this.id);
   }

   var TestObject = function (id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
   TestObject.prototype = new OtherObject ();

   var a = new TestObject("variable");
   a.test ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code

```
otherObject = function(id1){
    this.id = id1;
};

otherObject.prototype.test =function(){
    alert(this.id);
};

testObject = function(id2) {
    this.id=id2;
};

testObject.prototype = new otherObject("id2");/* id2 should be testObject this.id */


var a = new testObject("variable");
a.test();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
testObject = function(id2) {
    otherObject.call(this, id2); // run the parent object constructor with id2 parameter
    this.id=id2;
};

testObject.prototype = new otherObject(); // no id2 parameter here, it doesn't make sense
```

Note that while creating an instance of `testObject`, the constructor of `otherObject` is called twice - once to create the prototype and once to initialise the object.

To prevent duplicate initialisation, we can halt the constructor immediately when we are only using it to create the prototype.

```
otherObject = function(id1){
    if (typeof id1 == 'undefined') {
        /* as there is no parameter, this must be the call used to create
         * the prototype. No initialisation needed here, we'll just return.
         */
        return;
    }
    this.id = id1;
};
```

P.S. Please use capital camelcase with objects.

Comment: Don't call a constructor to create prototype objects at all!